# how to state a byte which value is -128 in the form of bit with java?

Tags: java

As we know, byte's range is between -128 and 127. I can state a byte variable in bit style which is prefixed with 0b. For example, 
`byte b = 0b111;`. But how can I state a byte which value is -128 in this style?

Comment: `byte b = (byte) 0b10000000;`

Comment: `b = -0b10000000;` doesn't need a cast.

Comment: And not to forget one can use underscores: `-0b1000_0000`.

Comment: See also [What is two's complement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/286538)

Comment: So enthusiastic. Thank you for all :)